# Detect 12/24 hour time display setting

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

When selecting some region formats in the phone you get an option in date+time where you can select if time should be displayed with 24h format.

Is there an way I can read that setting? I want time in my app to be displayed based on this setting?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, `ToString()` automatically uses current system settings, doesn't it?

Comment: Not the way I'm using it. I'm reading the data from the web (on the format 14:32) and need to format it to 14:32 or 2:32 PM depending on the phone settings.

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact(text, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString() gives me the correct time in the correct format but then I get the date aswell and I only want the time.

Comment: Well, then use the [correct overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx): `DateTime.ParseExact(text, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("t")`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link as well you can download all kinds off C#| VB Windows Smart Phone code 
   [Globalization Code and Downloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28VS.92%29.aspx)

This link is MSDN downloades should also help you with other things if you are coding for Windows Smart Phone

```
 // set this thread's current culture to the culture associated with the selected locale
            CultureInfo newCulture = new CultureInfo(cul);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;

            CultureInfo cc, cuic;
            cc = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            cuic = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;

            // display the culture name in the language of the selected locale
            regionalFrmt.Text = cc.NativeName;

            // display the culture name in the localized language
            displayLang.Text = cuic.DisplayName;

            // display the date formats (long and short form) for the  current culuture  
            DateTime curDate = DateTime.Now;
            longDate.Text = cc.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern.ToString() + " " + curDate.ToString("D");
            shortDate.Text = cc.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.ToString() + "   " + curDate.ToString("d");

            // display the time format (long form) for the current culture
            longTime.Text = cc.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern + "   " + curDate.ToString("T");
```

Comment: Can't find the flag for 24h display or 12h display.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [DateTimeFormatInfo documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shorttimepattern%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), "DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortTimePattern values do not change when the clock is set to 24 hours. The property values should become "h:mm" but remain "h:mm tt" where tt is AM or PM."

It looks like this is a bug and will *hopefully* be fixed in WindowsPhone8.

Anyway, to answer your question... You can use this:

```
string pattern = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern.Replace(":ss", "");
```

This was taken from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/).